# How to set the horizontal distance between outliers in gnuplot boxplot

Tags: gnuplot, boxplot

So if i have plotted some data in gnuplot as a boxplot (set style data gnuplot), and I have outliers having the same value, then they are plotted as dots horizontally at the same place.

How can I set that horizontal distance?

So for example I have the datafile data.dat

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
9
9
```

and plot it using

```
set style data boxplot
plot 'data.dat' using (1):1
set yrange [0:10]
```

How can I set then the distance between the two points at y=9?

Comment: No, you cannot change that distance. The position of duplicate outliers depends only on the selected pointsize. There if, however, a difference in the point distance between the command `plot 'data.dat' using (1):1` and `plot 'data.dat' using (1):1 pointsize 1`. But I suspect this shouldn't happen and is a bug...

Comment: That helps already a lot! Now using pointtype 0 and pointsize 1 in a logscale, the spacing isn't that bad.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot change that distance, The position of duplicate outliers depends on the selected pointsize. There is, however, a difference in the point distance between the command

```
plot 'data.dat' using (1):1
```

and

```
plot 'data.dat' using (1):1 pointsize 1.
```

But I suspect this shouldn't happen and might be categorized as bug.

```
set style data boxplot
set yrange[0:10]

plot 'data.dat' using (1):1 title 'no explicit point size',\
     '' using (2):1 pointsize 1 title 'point size 1'
```

[image]

Comment: This behavior seems to depend on the version. gnuplot 4.6.4 does not show any difference in this case.

Comment: OK, I checked it with 4.6.6 and 5.0

Answer (score 1):

Christoph, you were on the right track, just didn't go far enough.  At least with Ver. 5.0, the following worked for me:

```
set style boxplot outliers pointtype 6
plot 'data.dat' using (1):2:(0):1 pointsize .1
```

I was plotting a few thousand points, and this resulted in a much more reasonable plot, given that there could be tens of duplicates.
[Outliers that don't overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cOOZ.png)