# How to group boxplot outliers in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, boxplot, outliers

I have a large set of data points. I try to plot them with a boxplot, but some of the outliers are the exact same value and they are represented on a line beside each other. I found [How to set the horizontal distance between outliers in gnuplot boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28780544/how-to-set-the-horizontal-distance-between-outliers-in-gnuplot-boxplot), but it doesn't help too much, as it is apparently not possible.

Is it possible to group the outliers together, print one point and then print a number in brackets beside it to indicate how many points there are? I think this would make it more readable in a graph.

For information, I have three boxplots for one x value and that times six in one graph. I am using gnuplot 5 and already played around with the pointsize, which doesn't reduce the distance anymore.
I hope you can help!

Edit:

```
set terminal pdf
set output 'dat.pdf'
file0 = 'dat1.dat'
file1 = 'dat2.dat'
file2 = 'dat3.dat'
set pointsize 0.2
set notitle
set xlabel 'X'
set ylabel 'Y'
header = system('head -1 '.file0);
N = words(header)

set xtics ('' 1)
set for [i=1:N] xtics add (word(header, i) i)

set style data boxplot
plot file0 using (1-0.25):1:(0.2) with boxplot lw 2 lc rgb '#8B0000' fs pattern 16 title 'A'
plot file1 using (1):1:(0.2) with boxplot lw 2 lc rgb '#00008B' fs pattern 4 title 'B'
plot file2 using (1+0.25):1:(0.2) with boxplot lw 2 lc rgb '#006400' fs pattern 5 title 'C'
for [i=2:N] plot file0 using (i-0.25):i:(0.2) with boxplot lw 2 lc rgb '#8B0000' fs pattern 16 notitle
for [i=2:N] plot file1 using (i):i:(0.2) with boxplot lw 2 lc rgb '#00008B' fs pattern 4 notitle
for [i=2:N] plot file2 using (i+0.25):i:(0.2) with boxplot lw 2 lc rgb '#006400' fs pattern 5 notitle
```

What is the best way to implement it with this code already in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not option to have this done automatically. Required steps to do this manually in gnuplot are:

(In the following I assume, that the data file `data.dat` has only a single column.)

1. Analyze your data with `stats` to determine the boundaries for the outliers:

   ```
   stats 'data.dat' using 1
   range = 1.5 # (this is the default value of the `set style boxplot range` value)
   lower_limit = STATS_lo_quartile - range*(STATS_up_quartile - STATS_lo_quartile)
   upper_limit = STATS_up_quartile + range*(STATS_up_quartile - STATS_lo_quartile)
   ```
2. Count only the outliers and write them to a temporary file

   ```
   set table 'tmp.dat'
   plot 'data.dat' using 1:($1 > upper_limit || $1 < lower_limit ? 1 : 0) smooth frequency
   unset table
   ```
3. Plot the boxplot without the outliers, and the outliers with the `labels` plotting style:

   ```
   set style boxplot nooutliers
   plot 'data.dat' using (1):1 with boxplot,\
        'tmp.dat' using (1):($2 > 0 ? $1 : 1/0):(sprintf('(%d)', int($2))) with labels offset 1,0 left point pt 7
   ```

And this needs to be done for every single boxplot.

Disclaimer: This procedure should work basically, but having no example data I couldn't test it.

Comment: Thanks! This solution is really good. Only problem is that it prints out every point, even those where there is originally no point there if you print it with boxplot. Could you also take a look at the edit in my original post? I posted  what I'm using now, and I have to say I'm not as adapt at you at Gnuplot obviously. ;) Is it also possible to change point size and the size of the numbers? PS: It needs to be upper_limit and lower_limit in your second code snippet. ;)

Comment: When plotting the labels you must check if the number of counts is > 0, I edited the answer. You can change the pointsize as usual with e.g. `ps 2` and you can also use the `font` option when plotting `with labels`, like `plot ... with labels font ',12'`.

Comment: For testing purposes I used the pdf terminal, but I wanted to use it with cairolatex at the end. I realised that with cairolatex the points and labels are not printed at all. Do you know a way to circumwent it?

Comment: I could reproduce this error, when setting the `cairolatex` terminal at the beginning of the script. You must only set the `cairolatex` terminal and the output file directly before doing the actual plot, for `pdfcairo` it doesn't matter. Don't know why this happens.