# Remove duplicated outliers in gnuplot boxplot

Tags: statistics, gnuplot

I've large data files (more than 200K points), from which a want to generate boxplots.

In the one hand, I can only generate a clean plot when a get rid of outliers, once they spread in parallel to x axis. On the other hand, I want to keep the outliers, once they're important to my analysis. So, they shouldn't spread to the sides. As it seems, gnuplot does automatically spread the outliers when they are double. Someone already faced such problem? Any idea about how to show the outliers whithout spread them?

My gnuplot script is as follows:

```
set terminal png enhanced size 900,500
set output "saida.png"

set style fill solid 0.25 border -1
set style data boxplot

set xtics border in scale 0,0 nomirror norotate offset character 0, 0, 0 autojustify
set ytics border in scale 1,0.5 nomirror norotate offset character 0, 0, 0 autojustify

set ylabel "Y" 
set xlabel "X"

set style boxplot candles range  1.50 outliers pt 0 separation 1 labels auto sorted 

set yrange [ 4 : 10 ] noreverse nowriteback

set xtics ('1:1' 1, '4:3' 2, '2:1' 3)
plot '11.dat' using (1):1 notitle,  '43.dat' using (2):1 notitle,  '21.dat' using (3):1 notitle
```

The result is: 
[image]

Notice that "noise" over the whiskers: they are the outliers that I want to "correct".

Comment: See my answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/29386856/2604213 which shows how you can identify and count the outliers in gnuplot. Then you can plot these with e.g. `pointsize variables to keep some information about the number of outliers.

Comment: Thank you @Christoph! I've used your solution there to resolve my problem. As soon as I'm free, I will post an asnwer here, based in yours to present how the data appears. If the admins wish, this question could be marked as duplicate.